# nginx special directory whitelist extension

Tags: nginx, directory, whitelist, extension

How can i set white list extension for special directory for my virtual host.
I have bower installation of my webapp and i install many bower component into `bower_components` directiry of root of virtual host

```
/vhostroot
  /bower_components
  /foo
  /bar
  index.php
```

how can i set nginx white list extension on `bower_components` directory for example `css,js,woff` and etc...

my config doesn't work

```
  location /bower_components {
          if ($request_filename !~* \.(css|js|woff)$ ) {
                  return 403;
                  break;
          }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the way but it's good or not please offer me best way

```
  location ~ /bower_components {
          if ($request_filename !~* \.(css|js|woff)$ ) {
                  return 403;
                  break;
          }
  }
```